# Windows 10 Start Menu Critical Error

Tags: windows-10, start-menu

I upgraded my 8.1 laptop to windows 10. I was able to use my laptop for three weeks with no problem. However, when I open my windows 10 laptop while ago and press win logo in keyboard. This message display in my screen. "Critical error start menu. We'll fix it next time you sign in." So, I sign out for 3x but same message display in my screen whenever I press start menu. How would I fix it?

Comment: Weirdly uninstalling dropbox fixed it for me. Mine wasn't an upgraded win 10, just a fresh install.

Comment: On the latest windows version, everything I googled failed. I posted a new answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could resolve it by following these steps :

1. Press <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>
2. Type `Powershell` and ensure you have checked "create this task with administrator privileges"
3. Type the following code:

   ```
   Get-appxpackage -all *shellexperience* -packagetype bundle |% {add-appxpackage -register -disabledevelopmentmode ($_.installlocation + “\appxmetadata\appxbundlemanifest.xml”)}
   ```

   The above command will reinstall start menu
4. Once Powershell gets completed reboot your machine

Comment: "create this task with adminstrator privileges" cmd does not show this option

Comment: @janki You can search for it in the start menu, right-click it, then click "Run as administrator". Or on Windows 10 version 1703 or greater, press Win+X and click "Powershell (admin)".

Comment: @wjandrea you can't search in the start menu, that's the point of the question, it's broken.

Comment: The "run as admin" box is there on the task manager's run option.

Comment: This answer does not solve the problem here.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and resolved it with the following steps:

> In Windows, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to show the security screen.
>
> There, press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on the Shutdown symbol in the bottom right corner of the screen, then *Shutdown*.

After that, the system will reconfigure itself while shutting down. You can then restart your computer. During the following boot, my computer even needed to restart once, but after that I could log in again and the error was gone.

On another note, several forum posts indicate that this issue is caused by Avast antivirus, and goes away after uninstallation of this program. There might be something to it, because I use Avast too. If it should happen again, I will switch to the built-in Windows Defender.

**Edit:** it happened again pretty soon, I uninstalled Avast, it never happened again after that.

Answer (score -1):

On the latest version of Windows 10 all solutions I read failed. However it appears to go away if you just copy a working Windows local settings dir from a healthy user. Hence:

1. Create or have another admin user in the system (it probably needs for that user to have logged in at least once).
2. Copy the %localappdata%/Microsoft/Windows of that user to a temporary folder (as your normal/faulty  user).
3. From the temporary admin user backup your faulty user's %localappdata%/Microsoft/Windows and replace it.

PS. My problem was caused by an uknown software fault during a ccleaner cleanup operation so your mileage may vary.

Comment: People are horrible. The answer is legitimate. Yet in order to have their answers higher they downvote with ZERO arguments.

Comment: LOL. This conspiracy theory is of course totally baseless, but I guess 2020 was a very neurotic year.