# What does Shift+Shutdown do in Windows 10?

Tags: windows-10, shutdown, shift

I recently encountered the well-known [Critical Error: Start Menu and Cortana aren't working](https://superuser.com/questions/963928/windows-10-start-menu-critical-error) message:

[image: Critical Error: Start Menu and Cortana aren't working]

Signing out and in again did not help. But I found a solution on a [German website](http://washilftgegen.co/windows-10-schwerwiegender-fehler-menue-start-und-cortana-funktioniert-nicht/):

> In Windows, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Del</kbd> to show the security screen.
>
> There, press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click on the Shutdown symbol in the bottom right corner of the screen, then *Shutdown*.

It worked for me – Windows seemed to reconfigure itself during shutdown and during the following boot, during which it even restarted once.

What exactly does <kbd>Shift</kbd> do here? Is this documented somewhere?

Comment: It appears you are attempting to self-answer your question.  So write question, then submit an answer, a question should not have the answer contained within it.  *When this is a proper question I will reverse my vote.*

Comment: @Ramhound It is a proper question. He asks "What exactly does Shift do here? Is this documented somewhere?"

Comment: Related: [How to instruct Windows 8 NOT to perform a fast shutdown?](https://superuser.com/q/495240/443564)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Pressing the <kbd>Shift</kbd> key tells the PC to do a *full shutdown* rather than a [hybrid shutdown](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/how-windows-8-hybrid-shutdown-fast-boot-feature-works/).

[Source](http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/10/25/windows-8-windows-server-2012-faster-boot-process.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I'm using windows 10 v1909 and I do not have fast start enabled (just the default start up).  When I do a normal shut down it takes two minutes to fully shut down the computer and I have a SATA SSD drive for Windows.  However, if I hold down the shift key down momentarily when I click on shut down, the computer will shut down in 14 seconds.  I don't do this for a Windows update.