# Critical Error !! Start menu isnt working

Tags: windows-10, powershell

Whenever I clicked On Start Menu it will give error
i.e : Critical Error. your start menu isn't working.

[image: Error Image]

I tried to sign out to many times but it didnt work.

but when I create new user to this pc and hit start menu from there it will work properly.

I also trid this thing [Windows 10 Start Menu Critical Error](https://superuser.com/questions/963928/windows-10-start-menu-critical-error)
 Output:

```
Get-appxpackage : Access is denied.
Access is denied.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-appxpackage -all shellexperience -packagetype bundle |% {add-appx ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Get-AppxPackage], UnauthorizedAccessException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.UnauthorizedAccessException,Microsoft.Windows.Appx.PackageManager.Commands.GetApp
   xPackageCommand
```

[image: Powershell error]

How do I resolve this issue?

I Also try these full steps from [How to install start menu](http://home.bt.com/tech-gadgets/computing/has-your-windows-10-start-menu-stopped-working-here-are-four-ways-to-fix-it-11364000314532)
these thing also not working for me

thank You

Comment: Try again your PowerShell attempt, but from an elevated powershell (aka an Admin powershell)

Comment: It didnt give error.. but nothing doing.

Answer (score 1):

You can't reinstall the Shellexperiencehost (Your start menu).

Run a repair on your image using DISM /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth , or repair the installation using the installation medium.
If the Start menu troubleshooter doesn't work, the issue may lie with the AppX package itself, which you need to get from a repair.

http://aka.ms/diag_StartMenu

The get-appxpackage command reinstalls the package for the user ONLY using a parent package in C:\Windows\SystemApps , which if damaged has to be replaced by an in-place upgrade, reinstall, or repair.

Imagine it's akin to your ntoskrnl being damaged. You just can't pop a new one in, and even if you could, it's probably not the only thing broken in the image.

Check for corruption with SFC, use DISM, or repair it, to make it short and maybe not sweet. :(

Comment: TrobleShoot Gives Error : Requred application are not installed correctly. :(